# How old is Columbo?

Tags: columbo

Has Lt. Columbo's age ever been revealed, inferred, or commented upon?

I was reading [the Wikipedia page for the character](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo_(character)) and a lot of small details were found in episodes that I found very obscure (e.g. Columbo makes a single joke that is the only reference to the character also having a glass eye). However, I couldn't find how old the character was supposed to be at any point in the series. I was hoping maybe it was commented upon in the later stuff (TV movies?) which I am not so familiar with, but couldn't find anything there either.

Comment: or Jim Rockford for that matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has Lt. Columbo's age ever been revealed?

Not specifically that I can see and there is no mention of it in the character biography on Wikipedia,

What we **do** know (from Wikipedia) is that he served in the Korea War which ran from 1950 to 1953 which, if we assume his *minimum age* to be 18 (to enlist) would make his date of birth at least **1935**.

It should be noted that, according to [**Wikipedia**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo_(character))

> Over the years, the chatty Columbo would let slip many details about his personal life in conversations with suspects. However, in the episode "Dead Weight", Columbo more-or-less admits that he will sometimes make up certain details about his life, even fabricating fictional relatives, in order to establish a better rapport with a suspect. As a result, some of the following biographical details may be exaggerated or otherwise inaccurate, particularly those concerning his family life.

so it's possibe that some of the details from the bio (built from episode comments) are questionable.

*Frankly, as Peter Falk was born in 1927, I suspect that Lt Columbo's age was the same as Falk's*

Comment: Pretty much echoes my thought that shows made at this time chose actors who matched the roles as required.  No one really cared how old Columbo was, or Jim Rockford, or Rosco P Coltrane.  Times were simpler before the internet.

Comment: Do people really care about it that much now?  I haven't noticed a large push to establish characters' ages explicitly in more recent shows, anyway.

Comment: With the advent of Star Trek, Star Wars, and Harry Potter, there's an expectation that everything that happens in fictional screenplay can be documented, even when the original writers didn't feel the need to explain everything at the time of writing.

Comment: @Steve-O Do people *care*? Not really it's useless trivia really but such is the stuff that this site is built on. None of this really *matters* (he says bluntly) but it's a fun sidetrip nonetheless.